# Summation with exclusion

Tags: summation, notation

Commonly we use $\sum$ symbol to compactly describe the sum of a collection or a series, e.g. $\sum_{i=1}^{5} = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5$. Is it possible to describe the summation with a number removed from the series, like $1+2+4+5$, is it possible to use $\sum$ to describe this summation?

Comment: Or, you could do $$-3+\sum\limits_{i=1}^5i$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two ways:
$$\sum_{\substack{i=1\\i \ne 3}}^5 i$$
$$\sum_{i \in \{1,\dots,5\}\setminus \{3\}} i$$

If the ground set $\{1,\dots,5\}$ is clear from the context, you can even get by with just
$$\sum_{i \ne 3} i$$

Comment: Is it correct if writing $i=1,i\ne 3$ on the same line?

Comment: @YiYang if the comma does the function of a logical AND, and assuming our index is really an index, then I would answer you "Yes".

Comment: Just come up with another way to write it. If we define $K = 5$, then we can write $\sum_{i=1}^{[1,K]/3} i$? This seems more compact if the subscript and superscript are below and above the sigma symbol.

Comment: @YiYang, $i=1, i \not= 3$ looks fine to me, but your other proposal with $[1,K]/3$ is cryptic. In particular, $/$ looks like division rather than $\setminus$.  Also, the $1$ appears twice in that notation.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's more convenient to write

$$x_1+\ldots+\widehat{x_j}+\ldots+x_n$$

which is another way to denote

$$\underset{i\ne j}{\underset{1\le i\le n}{\sum}}x_i.$$